# How to manage a private key in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, cryptography

I am storing a private key for some crypto methods in an ASP.NET MVC application that is implemented in C#.  I am using the System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey class to create and retrieve the private key.

I create the key like this:

```
key = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP521, keyName, new CngKeyCreationParameters { ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport });
```

And I retrieve the key like this:

```
key = CngKey.Open(keyName);
```

This worked fine for the most part, but then on some deployments after the web application has been in production for a while I will start getting this error message when trying to retrieve the key.

> Cryptographic Operation
>   **SubjectDomainName** IIS APPPOOL
>   **ProviderName** Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
>   **AlgorithmName** ECDH_P521
>   **KeyType** User Key
>   **Operation** Open Key
>   **ReturnCode** 0x8009000b
>   **Log Name:** Security
>   **Task Category:** System Integrity

You will notice that it is using the Application Pool Identity, which is a virtual account.  I am suspicious that this is happening because this is a virtual account.  Keep in mind that it works fine for a while and then starts failing.  Has anyone else run into this issue and found a solution?  Is there a better what to manage the private key in an ASP.NET web application?

Comment: unrelated but its just took me 2 seconds to see your blacked out information by reverting the colours on the image, id suggest taking this image down and cutting them parts out of the image if these are private or a security risk.

Comment: I have cut the information out of the image for you and edited your post :) have a nice day, sorry i couldn't help on the question.

Comment: @David - Thanks for pointing this out. I just removed the image and added the relevant information as text.

Comment: I think that's just a general error message to say that the key could not be exported. Do you have any more info in event viewer like an IIS error ID?

Comment: @JamesP - This is the only error reported and it is in the Event Viewers Security Log.